# Trouble using a base Spock Specification and JenkinsRule with PluginManager

Tags: gradle, junit, jenkins-plugins, spock, jenkins-job-dsl

I want to use different sets of plugins for different Spock Specifications that extend an abstract BaseSpecification. I am having trouble doing that. From what I read, the `@WithPlugin` annotation didn't quite seem like what I need. So I've been trying to use `JenkinsRule.with(PluginManager)`.

I'm using the Groovy Spock framework and v2.59 of the Jenkins Unit Test Harness [org.jenkins-ci.main:jenkins-test-harness:2.59](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins-test-harness/releases/tag/jenkins-test-harness-2.59) to test [Jenkins Job DSL](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin) that we've written to automate the initialization of our Jenkins instances.

I have a `BaseSpecification` class where I declare a field `@Shared @ClassRule jenkinsRule = new JenkinsRule()`. As I understand it, the JenkinsRule is how we interact with the Jenkins Unit Test Harness and the embedded Jenkins instances. This has worked fine in the past for all Specifications that extend BaseSpecification and define their own feature methods.

But when I try to use something like `@Shared @ClassRule jenkinsRule = new JenkinsRule().with(getPluginManager())`, in the abstract BaseSpecification—where `abstract JenkinsRule getPluginManager()` is declared—if I return MyPluginManager.INSTANCE for some specs but not others, I keep getting the following error:

```
class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob is missing its descriptor
java.lang.AssertionError: class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob is missing its descriptor
  at jenkins.model.Jenkins.getDescriptorOrDie(Jenkins.java:1600)
  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob.getDescriptor(WorkflowJob.java:421)
  at hudson.model.ItemGroupMixIn.createProjectFromXML(ItemGroupMixIn.java:285)
  at jenkins.model.Jenkins.createProjectFromXML(Jenkins.java:3989)
  at javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.JenkinsJobManagement.createNewItem(JenkinsJobManagement.java:517)
  at javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.JenkinsJobManagement.createOrUpdateConfig(JenkinsJobManagement.java:141)
  at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractDslScriptLoader.extractGeneratedJobs_closure4(AbstractDslScriptLoader.groovy:204)
  at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
  at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
  at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractDslScriptLoader.extractGeneratedJobs(AbstractDslScriptLoader.groovy:197)
  at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractDslScriptLoader.extractGeneratedItems(AbstractDslScriptLoader.groovy:184)
  at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractDslScriptLoader.runScripts_closure1(AbstractDslScriptLoader.groovy:63)
  at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
  at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
  at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractDslScriptLoader.runScripts(AbstractDslScriptLoader.groovy:46)
  at BaseJobScriptsSpec.generateDslItems(BaseJobScriptsSpec.groovy:241)
  at BaseJobScriptsSpec.setupSpec(BaseJobScriptsSpec.groovy:38)
```

It seems like whichever PluginManager is used first changes state somewhere, either in a temporary file directory or elsewhere, that causes the error on the next test that uses a JenkinsRule with a different PluginManager. As it is now `MyPluginManager` is just a copy/paste of `org.jvnet.hudson.test.TestPluginManager` while I get this proof of concept to work.

What am I doing wrong here? Thank you.

---

EDIT 2021-08-04 Adding link to repo with reproduced error:

https://github.com/matthiasdenu/plugin-manager-bug/blob/main/src/test/groovy/CustomPluginMangerSpecification.groovy#L12

Comment: Are you able to share your code?

Comment: I created a skeleton project that reproduces the error https://github.com/matthiasdenu/plugin-manager-bug/blob/main/src/test/groovy/CustomPluginMangerSpecification.groovy#L12